# A human lifespan

Tags: human-biology

Recently, I read an article that said a human lifespan does not have any limit and when a man turns 105 he has a 50/50 chance to survive another year. Some scientists say that a man who will reach the age of 140 has already been born. Is it possible that the length of a human's life will be prolonged over time? I know that we don't know what the limit is and if it exists at all, but it is possible to one day expect it to be completely normal for a human being to live 300 years or so? I mean, without the intervention of any "elixirs of youth", development of technology, medicines etc.?

I ask because in 2016 there was an article published in ["Nature"](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature19793) that says we know what the limit is (115 years) and they believe that Jeanne Calment (who died at age 122) was lucky to live that long. On the other hand, another article published in ["Science"](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6396/1459) this year says that we don't know what the limit is.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Adding links to the articles that you discuss will improve this question.

Comment: "Nature": https://www.nature.com/articles/nature19793, "Science": http://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6396/1459

Comment: Looking at [these lists of oldest people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldest_people) a 'limit' of 115 seems unfounded. Also, Calment's actual age seems to be a somewhat controversial topic.